# PowerBI Dax. How to calculate value for each raw of visual table

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is it possible to create a measure to calculate sum for each row of the visual table just on the fly like in Excel.
I mean measure which could calculate values not directly in tables but in visual table

[image]

My test pbix

[download pbix](https://fastupload.io/en/ngaJJ1FA6dQ2eDi/file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a **calculated column** with

```
TOTAL = 'Table'[Column1] + 'Table'[Column2]
```

Then you simply pull this column into the table visual next to the 2 others.
If the columns are in different tables use this expression:

```
TOTAL = 'Table1'[Column1] + RELATED('Table2'[Column2])
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: No, because Column1 and Column2 are columns from different tables which are connected by Id. I've attached my test pbix https://fastupload.io/en/ngaJJ1FA6dQ2eDi/file

Comment: You didn't mention this in your question so I had to update my answer.